# Random IO errors on i2c

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, i2c

I connected a raspberry to a i2c bus that holds two devices: an i2c io expander `pcf8574A` at `0x20`, and a lcd controller `pcf8576` on address `0x38`.

Both show up fine when running `i2cdetect -y 1`.

When writing to the lcd controller, i seem to get occasionally IO errors. There is no pattern in when, sometimes two writes work fine, sometimes four, sometimes it fails three times, and the fourth is accepted again. When the data is accepted, the data on the LCD is correct. On the next write, my output looks garbled.

When connecting to an arduino, the whole system works fine. The arduino uses directly 5v though. I've tried adding a line shifter to make sure that is not the problem: the raspberry uses 3.3 volt, but I receive nicely a 5v on the other side, but the problem still remains.

I'm using the python with the SMbus module, and nothing in the code seems wrong I'm using the standard `write_i2c_block_data()` methods. I've tried all other variations like using `write_byte`, and I've even run directly with ioctl messages in plain C. All return on occasion IO errors, but not always. Initially I was thinking that the SMBUs interface would add things like an additional "count" on how many extra data bytes you are sending, but this isn't the case with `write_i2c_block_data`.

I've tried upping the clock to 400K, but this also does not work and I'm quite frankly running out of options.

I hope anyone else has some idea's that I can try. I don't have a oscilloscope so I can't look at the data directly unfortunately.

Comment: I2C I/O errors are invariably caused by poor connections.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured that might be the case, but i,ve replaced the cabling a few times. The same cabling is also used for the arduino connection so i've ruled out the cabling itself.

Comment: You may want to get one of these signal analyzers ...  http://www.ebay.com/itm/24MHz-8-Channel-USB-Logic-Analyzer-8-CH-Logic-Analyzer-for-Arduino-MCU-/191685084604   for less than $8 you can't go wrong and using these has allowed me to debug many a signal issue.